# Installing apache 2.4 on OS X Mavericks 10.9

Tags: apache, homebrew, osx-mavericks, libtool, apache2.4

I wanted to install apache 2.4 on my OS X Mavericks and having problem with `./configure` and `make`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

1. First thing you need homebrew on your mac. You can get with:

   ```
   ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/go/install)"
   ```

   command from [official homebrew website](http://brew.sh/).
2. Then you need to install pcre and libtool via:

   ```
   brew install pcre
   brew install libtool
   ```
3. After that, download latest stable apache 2.4 from [Apache](http://httpd.apache.org/download.cgi)
4. After extraction go inside directory and run the following:

   ```
   ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/apache-<VERSION> LTFLAGS=--tag=CC
   ```

   ex:

   ```
   ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/apache-2.4.7 LTFLAGS=--tag=CC
   ```

   which I found [here](https://github.com/jrwren).
5. After these steps, you just need to run

   ```
   make
   make install
   ```

   and the httpd configs and bash alters from [here](http://mac-dev-env.patrickbougie.com/apache/). Except make sure to use substitute in the correct paths.
6. In the end run

   ```
   httpd -k start working
   httpd -v
   ```

   you will get (except with your version number):

   > Server version: Apache/2.4.7 (Unix)
   >
   > Server built:   Feb  8 2014 14:34:44

Hope this saves your time.

Comment: I'm able to successfully compile and install Apache HTTPD Server v2.4.9 without updating/adding GNU Libtool. Also, I question the "need" for homebrew, here ("want", maybe). Installing PCRE is even easier than installing Apache. Download the [PCRE source code](http://www.pcre.org), configure, then make and install: `./configure --prefix=/usr/local && make && sudo make install`

Comment: I had to run `./configure --prefix=/usr/local/apache-2.4.9 LTFLAGS=--tag=clang CPP=/usr/bin/cpp` for Apache 2.4.9 on OSX Mavericks (10.3.9) or it would throw some errors and not configure.

Then I had to make a symbolic link because the `make` was looking for a path that didnt exist: `sudo ln -s /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/OSX10.9.xctoolchain`

Comment: I got an error on the `./configure ...` piece (step 4).  This fixed it:  http://mac-dev-env.patrickbougie.com/apache/

Comment: Why not just `brew install httpd24`? Seems needless to only partially use brew...

Answer (score 13):

Just a note that Apache httpd is by default installed on Mac OS X 10.9.x Mavericks. It can be started by the following command:

```
sudo apachectl start
```

The config file can be found at this path:

```
/private/etc/apache2/httpd.conf
```

Comment: But the original version of apache is not 2.4 but 2.2

Comment: @MarcinBobowski You're right. Mavericks has apache 2.2. I overlooked the difference in the version.

Answer (score 1):

I had to download apr and apr-util in srclib; unpack both and remove the versions at the end of the directory names.  Then run:

```
./configure --with-included-apr
```